# Code 16K barcode - checksum computation

Tags: barcode, checksum

I found 2 docs abouth this barcode.
None of them described fine how to compute checksum.

They both just give a formula and didnt say which characters to include in computation.

Also, these docs doesnt present integer values for start/stop/pad or rest special symbols. So if they are included in the computation i even dont know their values.

Does anyone know how to compute checksum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this information there : http://www.gomaro.ch/ftproot/Code%2016k.pdf
and there (more complete) : http://www.expresscorp.com/content/express/pdf/IndustrySpecifications/USS-16K.pdf

So this code has 2 checksums which are calculated by weighting the sum of the values of each character including the start character.

- The first check symbol starts the weighting at 2.
- The second starts weighting at 1.
- Next, take the modulo 107 of the sum.

So if you had the character values 22, 10, 15, 20, the two checksums would be:

```
 (2*22 + 3*10 + 4*15 + 5*20) % 107
 (1*22 + 2*10 + 3*15 + 4*20) % 107
```

If you have more characters just keep going... a general formula would be for n characters :

```
 C1 = modulo 107(sum((i+1)*Char(i))
 summed from i=1 to number of symbol character -2

 C2 =  modulo 107(sum(i*Char(i))
 summed from i=1 to number of symbol character -1 (so this includes C1)
```

Here is an image of the structure of a 16k code :
[image: Here is an image of the structure of a 16k code :]

Comment: The problem doc has no real example, which chars to include, which to exclude.

Comment: well I think you need to include all of them ... "which are calculated by weighting the sum of the values of each
character including the start character"

Comment: http://www.expresscorp.com/content/express/pdf/IndustrySpecifications/USS-16K.pdf This document seems more complete. You can also have a look at it... You can go directly to the `check characters` part

Comment: Thanks. I made some investigation and seems really need to include all chars except stop chars. And the value of pad for example is an index from the tables inside docs.

Comment: Yep, looks like you don't make any difference on the "meaning" of the characters. Which makes sense since the Checksum doesn't care about what's in the code but provides a way to know if what one decoded is exact.